# Python Crash Course 2 game: Error after creating bullet class

Tags: python

There is an error after adding bullet class. I am getting below error. I have typed all the code rather than copying. I have checked all the code, it looks same but still getting error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SQnL.png)
Below are my codes

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet


class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        """self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))"""
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def run_game(self):
        """start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self.bullets.update()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to key presses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to key presses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Respond to key releases."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group."""
        new_bullet = Bullet(self)
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip"""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

I am learning Python using Python crash course 2.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm the author of Python Crash Course, and the second part of @YevhenKuzmovych answer should resolve the issue. Bullet's `__init__()` method takes an instance of the overall game object as an argument, as you can see [here](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_12/shooting_bullets/bullet.py#L7). Your `_fire_bullet()` method looks correct. To clarify, `self` in `_fire_bullet()` refers to an instance of the game object, which gets passed to the `ai_game` parameter in `Bullet`'s `__init__()`. `self` in `Bullet`'s `__init__()` refers to a bullet object.

Comment: There's a longer explanation of how this pattern works [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/reader_questions/ship_self/). That explanation focuses on how the ship is created, but it's the same concept.

Comment: Please don't upload code as pictures. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bullet`s `__init__` doesn't have any arguments except `self` and `self` is passed implicitly. You probably need to use `bullet = Bullet()`.

If this is not the case and you actually need to pass the instance of `AlienInvasion` to the `Bullet`, its `__init__` should look something like this:

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, alien_invesion):
        ...
```